# Spring Boot JPA, OutOfMemory issue when loading entities at start up

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

I have a spring boot project which contains just entity definitions using JPA.

This is a dependency for several other Spring boot projects.

I have been using Spring boot 2.x i.e. Hibernate 5.x. and have now switched over to Spring boot 3, i.e. Hibernate 6.x.

The problem is that in the old versions the project start time was nominal. The new version projects now hang during the startup and eventually run out of heap space.
`

I have tried increasing the heap space using -Xmx5g but it makes no difference. Using top, I see the CPU usage goes through the roof before failing.

If I remove the entity dependency the startup is normal.

I have tried adding just 20 entites from another jar and that works fine, but with the real entity jar there are 121 entities.

I have added @EntityScan("com.xxx.entities") in my main application class.

The error stack trace is attached.

```
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name      'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource    [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Java heap space
    at     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(Abstra  ctAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1770) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:598) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:325) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1166) ~[spring-context-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:940) ~[spring-context-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:616) ~[spring-context-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.reactive.context.ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.java:66) ~[spring-boot-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:738) ~[spring-boot-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:440) ~[spring-boot-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316) ~[spring-boot-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306) ~[spring-boot-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295) ~[spring-boot-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
    at com.chiralcloud.ApigatewayApplication.main(ApigatewayApplication.java:14) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.base/java.util.HashMap.resize(HashMap.java:702) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.HashMap.putVal(HashMap.java:661) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.HashMap.put(HashMap.java:610) ~[na:na]
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.sql.internal.SqlAstProcessingStateImpl.resolveSqlExpression(SqlAstProcessingStateImpl.java:98) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.13.Final.jar:6.2.13.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.ast.spi.SqlExpressionResolver.resolveSqlExpression(SqlExpressionResolver.java:95) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.13.Final.jar:6.2.13.Final]
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.mapping.internal.BasicAttributeMapping.resolveSqlSelection(BasicAttributeMapping.java:340) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.13.Final.jar:6.2.13.Final]
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.mapping.internal.BasicAttributeMapping.generateFetch(BasicAttributeMapping.java:393) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.13.Final.jar:6.2.13.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.graph.FetchParent.generateFetchableFetch(FetchParent.java:108) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.13.Final.jar:6.2.13.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.ast.internal.LoaderSelectBuilder.lambda$createFetchableConsumer$3(LoaderSelectBuilder.java:986) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.13.Final.jar:6.2.13.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.ast.internal.LoaderSelectBuilder$$Lambda$1000/0x00007fc214927718.accept(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.hibernate.loader.ast.internal.LoaderSelectBuilder.visitFetches(LoaderSelectBuilder.java:805) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.13.Final.jar:6.2.13.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.ast.internal.LoaderSelectBuilder$$Lambda$993/0x00007fc214921528.visitFetches(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.hibernate.loader.ast.internal.LoaderSqlAstCreationState.visitFetches(LoaderSqlAstCreationState.java:150) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.13.Final.jar:6.2.13.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.graph.AbstractFetchParent.afterInitialize(AbstractFetchParent.java:30) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.13.Final.jar:6.2.13.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.graph.entity.AbstractEntityResultGraphNode.afterInitialize(AbstractEntityResultGraphNode.java:68) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.13.Final.jar:6.2.13.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.graph.entity.internal.EntityFetchJoinedImpl.<init>(EntityFetchJoinedImpl.java:58) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.13.Final.jar:6.2.13.Final]
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.mapping.internal.ToOneAttributeMapping.buildEntityFetchJoined(ToOneAttributeMapping.java:1383) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.13.Final.jar:6.2.13.Final]
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.mapping.internal.ToOneAttributeMapping.lambda$generateFetch$0(ToOneAttributeMapping.java:1542) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.13.Final.jar:6.2.13.Final]
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.mapping.internal.ToOneAttributeMapping$$Lambda$1004/0x00007fc21492a000.get(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.mapping.internal.ToOneAttributeMapping.withRegisteredAssociationKeys(ToOneAttributeMapping.java:1790) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.13.Final.jar:6.2.13.Final]
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.mapping.internal.ToOneAttributeMapping.generateFetch(ToOneAttributeMapping.java:1517) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.13.Final.jar:6.2.13.Final]
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.mapping.internal.ToOneAttributeMapping.generateFetch(ToOneAttributeMapping.java:108) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.13.Final.jar:6.2.13.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.graph.FetchParent.generateFetchableFetch(FetchParent.java:108) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.13.Final.jar:6.2.13.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.ast.internal.LoaderSelectBuilder.lambda$createFetchableConsumer$3(LoaderSelectBuilder.java:986) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.13.Final.jar:6.2.13.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.ast.internal.LoaderSelectBuilder$$Lambda$1000/0x00007fc214927718.accept(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.hibernate.loader.ast.internal.LoaderSelectBuilder.visitFetches(LoaderSelectBuilder.java:805) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.13.Final.jar:6.2.13.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.ast.internal.LoaderSelectBuilder$$Lambda$993/0x00007fc214921528.visitFetches(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.hibernate.loader.ast.internal.LoaderSqlAstCreationState.visitFetches(LoaderSqlAstCreationState.java:150) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.13.Final.jar:6.2.13.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.graph.AbstractFetchParent.afterInitialize(AbstractFetchParent.java:30) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.13.Final.jar:6.2.13.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.graph.entity.AbstractEntityResultGraphNode.afterInitialize(AbstractEntityResultGraphNode.java:68) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.13.Final.jar:6.2.13.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.graph.entity.internal.EntityFetchJoinedImpl.<init>(EntityFetchJoinedImpl.java:58) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.13.Final.jar:6.2.13.Final]
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.mapping.internal.ToOneAttributeMapping.buildEntityFetchJoined(ToOneAttributeMapping.java:1383) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.13.Final.jar:6.2.13.Final]
```